# Xpath - concatenate node name and text

Tags: xpath

On a given XML structure

```
<films>
  <title>Jaws</title>
  <year>1975</year>
  <title>Spaceballs</title>
  <year>1987</year>
</films>
```

How can i output the `node name` and `text` of each node concatenated with xpath? Like

```
title: Jaws
year: 1975
title: Spaceballs
year: 1987
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure XPath you need version 2.0: `//*[not(*)]/concat(local-name(), ': ', .)`. If you only have XPath 1.0 then you need to select the elements as already shown and then output name and contents.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<films>
  <title>Jaws</title>
  <year>1975</year>
  <title>Spaceballs</title>
  <year>1987</year>
</films>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$selector = new DOMXpath($doc);

foreach($selector->query('/films/*') as $child) {
    echo $child->nodeName . ': ' . $child->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

? Output:

```
title: Jaws
year: 1975
title: Spaceballs
year: 1987
```